# Solve an equation of 3rd order

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

What is the simplest method to solve an equation of 3rd degree.

For example:
$$-x^{3} + x^{2} + x - 1 = 0$$

Please I don't want the resolution of this equation I just want the simplest method to use to solve it, then I'll try to solve it on my own.

Comment: multiply both sides by -1 and try grouping method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$-x^{3} + x^{2} + x - 1 = 0$

$-x^{2}(x-1)+x-1=0$

$(x-1)(1-x^{2})=0$

$x=1$  and  $x^{2}=1$

$x=1 , x=-1$

Comment: He (or she) actually didn't want the answer, just the method ...

Comment: for 3 degree always not exist a algebra manner some time you have to use numerical analysis for a close answer as famous algoritms in numerical analysis

Comment: Yes you're absolutely right. However here it's not the case, and the OP seemed like he wanted to find the roots on his own and just wanted some hints to get going ;)

Comment: somaye's comment is completely untrue. There are closed form solutions for degrees 3 and 4, it only stops being the case after degree 5.

Comment: I like your method it's simple than the native one, but how did you pass from the second line to the third ?

Comment: (x-1) is a common you can factor it

Answer (score 0):

A possible method (if there's an easy first root to find : usually an integer not so far from $0$)

1. Find one root $r$ for the polynomial
2. Factor the polynomial by $(x-r)$
3. Solve the resulting 2nd degree polynomial